# Wrong ID provided at login

Tags: support, openid, google-openid

I used the wrong Gmail address when authenticating and now I can't change the account being used. Cancel doesn't help. I suppose I can dump my IE cache but the cancel really should reset the account being used.

Is there a way to override the Gmail account Stack Overflow thinks I want to use?

### Bug?

I just cleared everything from IE and reloaded. When I try to login using Google Stack Overflow still points to the wrong account:

```
using a login from: Google(wrongaccount@gmail.com
```

Comment: You can add a _different_ login and remove the bad one. Then add the correct one.

Comment: The OA page never offers to allow me to use a different login for Google - in insists on using the previous attempt's user name. I had to request a reset to get a link which worked.

Comment: Make sure you log off google before trying.